# Error al crear un constructor

Tags: java, constructor

El tema va sobre crear un constructor.

En el Estudiante.java me deja crear un constructor, pero en el código Intercambio.java, me da el siguiente error:

"Implicit super constructor Intercambio is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"

Porque no puedo crearlo?

**CÓDIGO DE Estudiante.java**

```
    package centro.educativo;

public class Estudiante extends Persona {

    //Atributos
     private String nombre;
     private String direccion;
     private String dataAlta;
     private int edad;
     private String nif;

     //Métodos


     //Método Constructor
     public Estudiante(String nombre, String direccion, String dataAlta, int edad, String nif) {
        super();

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.dataAlta = dataAlta;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nif = nif;
    }

    public Estudiante(String Persona, String dataAlta, int edad,String nif) {
        super();
    }
}
```

**CÓDIGO DE Intercambio.java**

```
    package centro.educativo;

public final class Intercambio extends Estudiante{

    public Intercambio( String Estudiante, String paisOrigen) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Comment: Lo primero que se puede apreciar es que estás montando mal tu modelo de datos. En la POO las cosas deberían funcionar como en la vida real (de hecho, esa es una de sus ventajas). El que `Estudiante` extienda de `Persona` es lógico, porque un `Estudiante` puede ser una `Persona`, pero el que `Intercambio` extienda de `Estudiante` es un disparate (con todo respeto). ¿Acaso un `Intercambio` puede ser un `Estudiante` en la vida real? Un `Intercambio` es una actividad en la cual un `Estudiante` podría participar. Si quieres que tu código refleje la realidad, `Intercambio` debería tener una ...

Comment: ... propiedad o miembro del tipo `Estudiante`, pero **NO** extender de `Estudiante`. Si entiendes y aplicas ese principio básico de la POO te evitarás modelar los datos (las clases) de la forma tan confusa en que lo estás haciendo. Ese es el verdadero error, que tienes tal lío con las clases, que al final no se sabe quién es quién. Por ejemplo, la llamada a `super()` en el 2º constructor de `Estudiante` no veo qué utilidad tendría realmente ¿?

Answer (score 0):

La clase `Intercambio` extiende de `Estudiante`, pero estas realizando el llamado a un constructor no existente, puedes realizar el llamado a cualquiera de los que tienes definido en la clase Estudiante, ya sea :

```
 public Estudiante(String nombre, String direccion, String dataAlta, int edad, String nif)
```

o

```
 public Estudiante(String Persona, String dataAlta, int edad,String nif)
```

Agregando `super()` con los parámetros del método que desees utilizar, por ejemplo si usas el primer constructor, puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
public final class Intercambio extends Estudiante{

        public Intercambio( String Estudiante, String paisOrigen) {
              super(Estudiante, paisOrigen, "", 0, "");

        }    

}
```

si usas el segundo, de esta forma:

```
package centro.educativo;

public final class Intercambio extends Estudiante{

    public Intercambio( String Estudiante, String paisOrigen) {
        super(Estudiante, paisOrigen, 0, "");
    }
}
```

---

De otra forma simplemente agrega un constructor que tenga los dos parámetros que necesitas, esto dentro de tu clase `Estudiante` :

```
public class Estudiante extends Persona {

    public Estudiante(String Persona, String paisOrigen) {
        super();
    }

}
```

así no tendrías que modificar tu clase `Intercambio` :

```
    package centro.educativo;

public final class Intercambio extends Estudiante{

    public Intercambio( String Estudiante, String paisOrigen) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te da porque en `Persona` no existe un constructor sin parámetros.
Ahí  en los constructores de `Estudiante` haces `super()` pero debes de pasarle los parámetros del constructor padre. Es decir: `super(estudiante,paisOrigen);` o en su defecto crear un constructor sin parámetros en `Persona`.